# TreeDropdownField Silverstripe 4 Navigation Labels

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I work on a SilverStripe 4 project where I use the TreeDropdownfield. In 3.6 it got the MenuTitle (Navigation Label) by default, but I noticed that in SilverStripe the default page titles are being displayed.

Since my customer changed the page titles the TreeDropdownField shows long page titles. I would like to display the Navigation labels instead of those long page titles because the structure isn't clear with those long titles.

I have the following code:

```
<?php

use SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject;
use SilverStripe\CMS\Model\SiteTree;

use SilverStripe\Forms\FieldList;
use SilverStripe\Forms\TextField;
use SilverStripe\Forms\TreeDropdownField;

class InternalLink extends DataObject {
    private static $db = [
        'Title'                 => 'Varchar',
    ];
    private static $has_one = [
        'LinkTarget'            => SiteTree::class,
        'InternalLinkCategory'  => 'InternalLinkCategory'
    ];

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', TextField::create( 'Title', 'Titel link' ) );
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', TreeDropdownField::create( 'LinkTargetID', 'Doeladres', SiteTree::class ) );

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like we over override title with navigation lable, but it does not work for me,  
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', TreeDropdownField::create( 'LinkTargetID', 'Doeladres', SiteTree::class , 'ID', 'MenuTitle' ) );



[http://api.silverstripe.org/4/SilverStripe/Forms/TreeDropdownField.html#method___construct]( see here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `TreeDropdownField::setTitleField()`. It sets the field to use for item title.

```
$treeField = TreeDropdownField::create('LinkTargetID', 'Doeladres', SiteTree::class);
$treeField->setTitleField('MenuTitle');
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $treeField);
```